# How to deal with zero inflated columns in dataset?

Tags: distributions, modeling, dataset, zero-inflation

I have a dataset on which I am trying to fit a Linear Regression model. It has 4 independent variables. I am trying to predict my dependent variable using these four columns. However, 2 out of these 4 columns contain data that has value 0 (40% to 55%). So when I plot my data for each column it shows zero-inflated right-skewed distribution. I tried using data transformation by applying log(x+1) but it does not create any significant impact.
My model r2_score is = 0.44 which is not improving. I have a couple of questions here.

1- Is my assumption correct that these columns are messing up my choice of using a linear regression model?

2- What is the best choice of the model if linear regression is not the right one.

3- How do you deal with such kind of data?

I am using python for modeling this data

Comment: What kind of variable is the dependent variable ? Do you have excess zeros only in the independent  variables ?

Comment: @RobertLong dependent variable is like a count for views variable, it has very less zero as compare to independent

Answer (score 1):

It's not the distribution of the independent variables that is important. It's the distribution of the outcome. If it is a count variable and not zero inflated then you should consider fittig a poisson or negative binomial (in case of under/over dispersion) generalised linear model (glm)

Comment: Does this answer your question ? If so please consider marking it as the accepted answer. If not please let us know why so that it can be improved